# What conditions could make the commutator $[M^*,M] = M^*M - MM^*$ full-ranked? $M$ is not normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Let $M$ be complex, full-ranked, and not normal i.e. $M\ne M^*$.

Is $M^*M - MM^*$ also full-ranked?

---

**Edit:**

If there is any, what condition(s) could make the commutator $[M^*,M] = M^*M - MM^*$ full-ranked? $M$ is not normal.

If it helps, I know that $M^*M$ is full-ranked which implies that $MM^*$ is also full-ranked.

Comment: Since $[M^\ast,M]=[M^\ast-\bar\lambda I,M-\lambda I]$ for every number $\lambda$, your condition about the rank of $M$ is useless.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the title and question following your comment.